# Map for text based game

Tags: python

this is supposed to make a map for a text based game which works great until I add more than one point to the map when I add a second point to it, it makes the length of the map 2x bigger than needed

this is example with 2 points

```
mapS = [5,5] ##Size of the map

line = ""

objects = dict()

numx = 0
numy = 0


def mapSize(x,y):
    mapS = [x,y]

def addObject(name, x, y, symbol):
    globals()[name] = [x,y, symbol]
    objects[name] = [x,y, symbol]

addObject("House", 2,3, "H") ##############FIRST POINT
addObject("Cabin", 3,4, "C") ##############SECOND POINT

for y in range(mapS[1]):
    numy += 1
    for x in range(mapS[0]):
        numx += 1
        for place in objects:
           if objects[place][0] == numx:
                if objects[place][1] == numy:
                    line += objects[place][2]
                else:
                    line += "*"
            else:
                line += "*"        
    print(line)
    line =""
    numx = 0
numy = 0
```

Comment: I doubt this is your problem, but using `globals()` like this is a very bad idea. If you want a global dictionary of things that can be accessed by name, just create a global dictionary, like `d = {}`, and do `d[name] =` instead of `globals()[name] =`. The only reason to ever push things into globals is when you have some code that has to access them statically and other code that has to access them dynamically.

Comment: Meanwhile, your `mapSize` function does nothing; it creates a local variable named `mapS`, which temporarily hides the global of the same name, then it immediately exits and that local goes away. If you want to reassign to a global variable from inside a function, you need a `global mapS` statement.

Comment: I tried that and nothing changed.

Comment: Also, you're comparing `numx` and `numy` both against the `x` value (`objects[place][0]`), instead of comparing `numy` against the `y` value.

Comment: When you have many errors in your program, fixing just one of them isn't likely to solve all of your problems. But you still have to fix that one, and you have to fix all the others too.

Comment: Okay ill fix the mapsize thing too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that, for each `y` and each `x`, you're printing one character for each object:

```
for y in range(mapS[1]):
    numy += 1
    for x in range(mapS[0]):
        numx += 1
        for place in objects:
            if objects[place][0] == numx:
                if objects[place][0] == numy:
                    line += objects[place][2]
                else:
                    line += "*"
            else:
                line += "*"
```

So, if you have 2 objects, you'll print 2 characters at each x, y point; if you have 6 objects, you'll print 6 characters at each x, y point.

What you want to do is only print 1 character at each x, y point. For example:

```
for y in range(mapS[1]):
    numy += 1
    for x in range(mapS[0]):
        numx += 1
        for place in objects:
            if objects[place][0] == numx and objects[place][0] == numy:
                line += objects[place][2]
                break
        else:
            line += "*"
```

This goes through the objects until it finds the first one that matches that position, and adds only that one object's character, and stops searching with `break`. Then, only if it gets to the end of the loop without `break`ing (that's what an `else` clause on a `for` statement means), it adds a `*` instead.

---

You have a number of other problems here:

- `mapSize` doesn't actually change `mapS`; you need a `global mapS` statement.
- You're comparing both `numx` and `numy` to `objects[place][0]`. You almost certainly wanted to compare `numy` to `objects[place][1]`. One nice way to do this all at once is: `if objects[place][:2] == [numx, numy]:`.
- Your `numx` and `numy` are 1-based. Did you want that? If so, it would make your intention more explicit—and a whole lot simpler—to just use `numx == x+1` instead of keeping track of it separately from `x` but in such a way that it always ends up the same as `x+1`. If not, just use `x` itself.
- The `globals()[name] =` is a bad idea. Since you don't make any use of it, the simplest way to fix that is to just remove that line.
- It's a lot simpler to create things like `line` at the top of the loop, instead of creating them outside the loop and then re-creating them at the bottom of the loop.

So, putting it all together:

```
mapS = [5, 5]

objects = {}

def mapSize(x, y):
    global mapS
    mapS = [x, y]

def addObject(name, x, y, symbol):
    objects[name] = [x, y, symbol]

addObject("House", 2, 3, "H") ##############FIRST POINT
addObject("Cabin", 3, 4, "C") ##############SECOND POINT

for y in range(mapS[1]):
    line = ""
    numy = y+1
    for x in range(mapS[0]):
        numx = x + 1
        for place in objects:
            if objects[place][:2] == [numx, numy]:
                line += objects[place][2]
                break
        else:
            line += "*"        
    print(line)
```